# Create Settings Page - UISegmented

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am creating a settings menu for my app. I want to use the UITableViewController, I added in a UISegmentedControl to change color of label (Green, blue, red). Although this only works when the label is on the same page as the SegmentedController. aka same .h .m file. I want to control the labels on the first view controller. How exactly would I do that? Also what if i wanted to add in a vibrate toggle switch. How can i access first view controllers labels with second view controllers actions? And is making A view controller + TableViewcontroller the correct way of doing this or should it be different. Please help. This is my segmented code.

```
- (IBAction)colorController:(id)sender {

if (Controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {

    //App title text color
     appTitle.textColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:1.00 green:1.00 blue:0.00 alpha:1.0];

    //Background color when selected
    Controller.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.00 green:1.00 blue:0.00 alpha:1.0];

    //The font of the selected
    NSDictionary *fontColor = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [UIColor blackColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                               nil];
    [Controller setTitleTextAttributes:fontColor forState:UIControlStateSelected];



}
if (Controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {

    //App title text color
    appTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.00 green:0.66 blue:1.00 alpha:1.0];

    //Background color when selected
    Controller.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.00 green:0.66 blue:1.00 alpha:1.0];

    //The font of the selected
    NSDictionary *fontColor = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [UIColor whiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                               nil];
    [Controller setTitleTextAttributes:fontColor forState:UIControlStateSelected];

}
if (Controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {

    //App title text color
    appTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.98 green:0.22 blue:0.22 alpha:1.0];

    //Background color when selected
    Controller.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.98 green:0.22 blue:0.22 alpha:1.0];


    //The font of the selected
    NSDictionary *fontColor = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [UIColor whiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                               nil];
    [Controller setTitleTextAttributes:fontColor forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
if (Controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 3) {

    //App title text color
    appTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.82 blue:0.44 alpha:1.0];

    //Background color when selected
    Controller.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.82 blue:0.44 alpha:1.0];

    //The font of the selected
    NSDictionary *fontColor = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
    [Controller setTitleTextAttributes:fontColor forState:UIControlStateSelected];

}
```

As you can see, "appTitle" is on the first view controller. And how do i make it so the state of Segmented control stays how i clicked on it? It always resets once i get back.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the Protocol in your required class. Add required delegate methods & call it based on your need. This way you can resolve your issue.

Refere tutorial links for it

[Apple Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html)

[Delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)

[Objective-C & Swift both](http://codewithchris.com/learn-swift-from-objective-c-part3/)